# Getting File Size and Setting the Seek Pointer in Windows

Tags: c, windows, file, file-io

I'm trying to get this size of a file using the following method:

```
size_t  fsize = 0;
fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_END);
fsize = ftell(fin);
fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

The file in question is a bit over 2GiB, and ftell returns some giant number.

My application also requires the seek pointer to be set back a number of bytes after every read. I used the following.

```
i = fread(inbuf, 1,readSize, fin);
fseek(fin, -16, SEEK_CUR);
```

After every read, I check if `i` equals 16, which should normally occur if I reached the end of the file after the last fread. However, this doesn't work either and a value of zero is assigned to `i`, indicating that the seek pointer was not moved back.

I should note that my program works just fine in Linux, and has been tested with different read and file sizes. The code is nearly identical to the Linux version of the code. The difference being that I couldn't use the `stdint` library from C99 in Windows. Other than that, the code is exactly the same. The Linux version works fine using the exact same test file and read size.

Finally, I should mention that this is a CUDA program (runtime version 4.2), using VS2010, on Win7. This is a 64-bit program.

**EDIT**

This file was opened with the 'b' flag. Here is the code:

```
if(!(fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb")))
{
    printf("The input file: %s could not be opened\n", argv[1]); 
    err = -5; goto exit;
}

if(!(fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb")))
{
    printf("The output file: %s could not be opened\n", argv[1]); 
    err = -6; goto exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fstat() can be used to get the size of the file. This is better than reading the file to calculate the size .[fstat in msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246905%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

EDIT: 
I am not too sure about the behaviour of fstat on Windows though.

Comment: That might work, but this requires using file handles instead of the standard file pointer. Is there any way to get one from the other.

Comment: Use the `fileno` function to get the file descriptor from a `FILE*`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx(v=vs.80).aspx  :Seems like it should work. Just elaborating a bit more on stat() system call or fstat() : If you are using those functions,you are avoiding the need for doing an unnecessary disk access.The file size is just one piece of  metadata about the file that is held in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Opening your file in binary (with `O_BINARY`) might help. Otherwise, you might occur problems with libne breaks and EOF characters.

Comment: Since the OP is using `FILE` and probably `fopen`, the mode string should contain `"b"` which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: It is as @JoachimPileborg said. I was using fopen, however the file was already opened with the `"b"` flag. I've updated the question.